# How to pass optional params when connecting to node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am connecting to node.js using express Eureca.io.

```
        var express = require('express')
      , app = express(app)
      , server = require('http').createServer(app);


    // serve static files from the current directory
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

     //// 
    //get EurecaServer class
    var EurecaServer = require('eureca.io').EurecaServer;

   eurecaServer.attach(server);

//detect client connection
eurecaServer.onConnect(function (conn) {    
    console.log('New Client id=%s ', conn.id, conn.remoteAddress);
})
```

And, I want to pass one parameter to server when a client is connected. Please let me know how can I do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you want is passing something from the client to the server, you can't do it inside onConnect function.

what you need here is defining a server side function and call it from the client. also your server implementation is wrong.

let's say your server side function is called init() and take the parameter you want to send to the server, your server code becomes

```
var express = require('express')
   , app = express(app)
   , server = require('http').createServer(app);
// serve static files from the current directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


var Eureca = require('eureca.io');
var eurecaServer = new Eureca.Server();

eurecaServer.exports.init = function(param) {
     //do what you want with param

     //if you want to get the client connection id you can use the code bellow
     var connID = this.socket.id;
}

eurecaServer.attach(server);
//detect client connection
eurecaServer.onConnect(function (conn) {    
   console.log('New Client id=%s ', conn.id, conn.remoteAddress);
})
```

then in the client side you do

```
<head>
  <script src="/eureca.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var eurecaClient = new Eureca.Client();

        eurecaClient.ready(function (serverProxy) {
               serverProxy.init('hello'); //<==== here you call the server side init, and you pass 'hello' as parameter
        });

</script>
</body>
```